# Xtragridview view paging style

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, xtragrid, custompaging

I have problem about VB.NET with Xtragrid from DEV EXPRESS.
This is my Xtragrid built by code.
At the footer built by this code :

```
gridVWKeluar.Columns(4).SummaryItem.SummaryType = DevExpress.Data.SummaryItemType.Sum
gridVWKeluar.Columns(4).SummaryItem.DisplayFormat = "{0:n2}"
gridVWKeluar.Columns(3).SummaryItem.SummaryType =DevExpress.Data.SummaryItemType.Custom
gridVWKeluar.Columns(3).SummaryItem.DisplayFormat = "Total"
gridVWKeluar.OptionsView.ShowFooter = True
```

[image: This is my XtraGridview]

And the problem is : i want to add footer again by code ofcourse (not properties) with paging system like this .....(this picture taken from http://demos.devexpress.com/ASP/Performance/ but that xtragrid just for asp.net and i need that in VB.NET)
[image]

thanks for reading and answer ^_^
GBU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GridControl itself does not support this "Paging UI" and it is not quite clear to me why you need the "paging" instead of displaying all the data with scrolling in WinForms application.
If you thinking that you'll run into problems with a scrolling performance due to large amount of data, take a look at [server data-binding modes](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument8398). These are specifically designed to work with large data-sets consisting of more than 50,000 records (the specific amount of data depends on your circumstances).  You can bind the GridControl to the large data-source synchronously or asynchronously, and keep a capability to perform sorting, filtering and grouping operations against the entire data source.

Comment: thats what i found my problem....my data is too much.....thanks for understanding my situation